# HBase Intra-row scanning

Tags: node.js, rest, hbase

I am trying to find some information on intra-row scanning through HBase REST API. However, I have a hard time to see how it could be done according to the documentation, and I am wondering if anyone used this feature from the REST interface?

References

- http://hadoop-hbase.blogspot.jp/2012/01/hbase-intra-row-scanning.html
- http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate

More specifically, I am looking into how I would do this from a Node.js application.

Edit:

I found this, but I have a hard time to see how intra-row scanning would be possible...

[HBase REST Filter ( SingleColumnValueFilter )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302097/hbase-rest-filter-singlecolumnvaluefilter)

Answer (score 0):

I still have to test this further, but I have written a document which gives a few examples of stringified filter as per the HBase REST Filter question.

Basically, from what I see it is possible to use FilterList and stack multiple Filters in a JSON array.

More details: https://gist.github.com/3979381

Still have to try it, but it seems like this should work. Will update once I have tried it through the REST API.